# Subarray around given element (or index)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, arrays

Given an array of up to 24 unique elements and a specific element (or index) in the that array, how can I find the subarray of up to 12 elements made of elements "around" that index?

By around I mean that if there are enough elements before and after the index, it should be in the middle of the subarray. If there are too few elements before, more should be taken after the index to reach the target of 12 elements, even if the index is not in the middle of the resulting subarray.

I am not able to solve this seemingly simple problem.

I have solved some trivial cases but I couldn't find a generic solution...

`if array.length <= 12` the whole array is the solution

When the array is made of exactly 24 elements (which it may not be), and the index is between 6 and 18, the subarray is `array[index - 6, 12]`

If the index is 0, the subarray is `array[0, min(12, array.length)]`

I'm using ruby for this, but feel free to use any language of your choice :)

A few examples to clarify:

```
# Wanted element in the middle:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
                                  #^^

# Expected result:

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
                   #^^

# Wanted element in the middle:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
                                  #^^

# Expected result:

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
                   #^^

# Wanted element is early:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
      #^

# Expected result:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
      #^

# Wanted element is late:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
                                                                      #^^

# Expected result:

[ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
                                 #^^

# Less elements:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
                                  #^^

# Expected result:

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
                         #^^
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ruby arrays support `arr.drop(n)` and `arr.take(n)` to drop initial and take subsequent elements, so when you array is greater than 12 in length just drop (length-12)/2 and then take 12 elements.

NB: You might want to consider the case when the array has 13 elements, is the answer the 1st 12 or the last 12 characters?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
arr.drop((arr.length-12)/2).take(12)
```

The above works for finding the 12 elements in the middle of the array of 15, to generalise this you need to think of a way to work out how many elements to drop before you take your 12 elements when given a random index.

It's hard to be more specific as I'm not 100% sure what it is that you want, a few actual examples would be helpfull.

**Update after question edited:**

It looks like what you need to do is work out the range of the elements that you want so in psuedo code:

```
idx = <The index of the element to select around>
startIdx = idx - 6 ;
endIdx   = idx + 5 ;

if startIdx < 0 then take the 1st 12 elements
else if endIdx > arr.length then
   drop arr.length - 12 elements
else
   drop startIdx elements
   take 12 elements
```

Comment: That does not consider the wanted index!! This method preserves the center of the array (8), which is acceptable if the index is 8. But if the index is 0 it should return [ 1, 2, ..., 12 ] and if the index is 14, it should return [ 4, 5, ..., 15 ]. Didn't know about #drop though. Thanks

Comment: I do not have a ruby console right now, so I cannot test the code to choose the answer. But it seems logically correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do that.

**Code**

```
def sub(arr, target_ndx, max_size, bias = :LEFT)
  arr_size = arr.size 
  return arr if arr_size <= max_size

  diff = arr_size - max_size
  left = diff/2 - 1
  left += 1 if diff.even? && bias == :RIGHT
  right = left + max_size-1

  return arr[left, max_size] if (left..right).cover?(target_ndx)

  left = target_ndx+1-(max_size+1)/2
  left -= 1 if max_size.even? && bias==:RIGHT
  left = [left, 0].max
  left = [left, arr_size-max_size].min
  arr[left, max_size]
end
```

**Examples**

```
sub([*0..23], 11, 12)         # mid
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
sub([*0..23], 11, 12, :RIGHT) # mid
  #=> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
sub([*0..23], 2, 12)          # early
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
sub([*0..23], 20, 12)         # late
  #=> [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
sub([*0..14], 11, 12)         # fewer
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
sub([*0..23], 7, 3)
  #=> [6, 7, 8]
sub([*0..23], 17, 3)
  #=> [16, 17, 18]
sub([*0..23], 6, 4)
  #=> [5, 6, 7, 8]
sub([*0..23], 6, 4, :RIGHT)
  #=> [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: The early case is my mistake, while the fewer case is correct. Actually I would like the target element to be surrounded by other elements whenever possible (always unless it's the first or the last). So while the first cases are correct, the last four are not exactly what I wanted. [6,7,8] [16,17,18] and [8,9,10,11] or [7,8,9,10] (for the last two cases, indifferently) should have been the outputs. Thanks for your work!!!

Comment: I tweaked the code. Please see if it now conforms with your requirements. Incidentally, I changed my last two examples because the target index was in fact in the middle section.